# Receiving Uploaded Files to ASPX page without HtmlInputFile

Tags: c#, file, upload

I'm trying to create a web form (c#) that will receive file uploads from various HTML forms. All of the examples I'm finding involve using HTMLInputFile, which doesn't help me. The forms will not be on my site, so basically I need a web form just to process posted files. I've tried using Request.Files in Page_Load, but the collection is always zero. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) API to upload file to server, But if you want to upload the file to FTPServer you can use System.NET.FtpWebRequest or some open source ftp libraries.

Comment: The pages that will do the posting are not .net, just HTML. My problem is how do I grab those files when they are posted to my web form?